# What are the differences between set -g, set -ga and set-option -g in a .tmux.conf file?

Tags: configuration-files, tmux

I'm new to tmux and trying to understand it's configuration. I've started with looking at some pre-existing .tmux.conf files and whatever documentation I can find but it still leaves me wondering about the flags. I've seen the following so far:

A few examples from the [ArchWiki entry on tmux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Configuration)

```
set -g prefix C-a  
set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-termite:Tc"
set-option -g xterm-keys on
```

And one line from a [.tmux.conf file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108330/tmux-copy-mode-search-highlight)

```
set-window-option -g
```

What do the flags mean and are there any particular cases when one flag is preferable over another?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`set` is the alias of `set-option`.

`set -g` is used to set global options and `-ga` appends values to existing settings.

From Tmux's man page:

> With -a, and if the option expects a string or a style, value is
>   appended to the existing setting.  For example:
>
> ```
>    set -g status-left "foo"
>    set -ag status-left "bar"
> ```
>
> Will result in ‘foobar’.  And:
>
> ```
>    set -g status-style "bg=red"
>    set -ag status-style "fg=blue"
> ```
>
> Will result in a red background and blue foreground.  Without -a, the
>   result would be the default background and a blue foreground.

`set-window-option` (alias `setw`) is used to configure window options (`allow-rename`, `mode-keys`, `synchronize-panes`, etc.) and the same flag options are available.

See:

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux
- https://superuser.com/questions/758843/difference-between-global-server-session-and-window-options

Comment: Hm, the tmux 3.0a man page doesn't explain `setw` nor `set-window-option`. Also, `set-option` has a `-w` for window options, as well.

Comment: @maxschlepzig - ever figured out what happened? Are they deprecating `set-window-option`? I still don't see an entry for `set-window-option` on tmux manual.

Comment: @rgin Yes, a [2008 entry](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/1a11c972aed11c1996d732f15ad16f02c668b5a0/CHANGES#L3018-L3019) in the tmux `CHANGES` files documents `setw` as an alias to `set-window-option`, a [2010 entry](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/1a11c972aed11c1996d732f15ad16f02c668b5a0/CHANGES#L1968-L1969) documents `set-window-option` as a new alias to `set-option -w` and the [tmux 3.0 entry](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/1a11c972aed11c1996d732f15ad16f02c668b5a0/CHANGES#L759-L760) announces the de-documentation of  `set-window-option`.